# Why Mockito.when(...).doReturn(...) not working as expected if it called from Mockito.doAnswer(...)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I need to test a method which creates `Car` object and uses `CarDao` to save it in database. Another method gets created `Car` object but if `CarDao` is mock then `car.getUser()` returns `null` instead of correct `User` object. This is my code.

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            lastCarId++;
            Car car = (Car) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
            // here car.getUser() returns correct user object
            car.setId(lastCarId);
            Mockito.when(carDao.getById(car.getId())).thenReturn(car);
            return null;
        }
    }).when(carDao).persist(Mockito.any());
```

Why `carDao.getById(carId).getUser()` returns null? And what I need to do to get full object with correct `user` field value?

**Updated**

`carDao` usage:

```
Car car = carService.create("car name1", "color", "year", user); // in this method called carDao.persist(...);
car.setColor("color2");
carService.findById(car.getId());
// this method calls carDao.getById(carId) 
// and comapres with authenticated user ID. 
// But carDao.getById(carId) returns car with user == null
```

Below is the part of `CarService` class where the code throws NullPointerException.

```
// carService.findById(...) method
public Car findById(Car id) {
    Car car = carDao.getById(id);
    User carUser = car.getUser(); // returns null
    User currentUser = accountService.getAuthenticatedUser(); // returns correct user object
    if (!carUser.getId().equals(currentUser.getId())) { // throws NullPointerException
        return null;
    }
    return car;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is your `User` object set in your `car` object that you retrieved from `invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];`? If not, need to check why it is null

Comment: @Draken, Yes `User` object is set in the `car` object I retrived from `invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];`

Comment: At what point are you checking the `carDao.getById(carId).getUser()` property? Can we see your section where that is called?

Comment: @Draken, I've added the `carDao` usage. Check it please.

Comment: Can you also post your code for `carService.findById(car.getId());`

I assume your `carService` hasn't been mocked also?

Comment: @Draken, I've added the `carService.findById(...)` implementation into the question. Check it please.

Comment: What is the point to have some instrumentation (ie. mock do something) into a response??? You probably want to move the inner Mockito.when.

Comment: Could you pull the `Mockito.when(carDao.getById(car.getId())).thenReturn(car);` out of the internal method, instead declare a `Car` object and set that in the internal method, then in your test method add the returning of that `Car` object?

I have a feeling Mockito doesn't like inner methods

Comment: Also, can you confirm the car ID is the same number at the following lines:
`Mockito.when(carDao.getById(car.getId())).thenReturn(car);`
`carService.findById(car.getId());`

Comment: I believe that you make something wrong, because I simulate your example and it works fine. I mean inner `when` works!

Comment: @Draken, I cannot pull it out of the internal method because `car` object has a unique md5 hash field. car IDs are the same. I've already debugged it.

Comment: @Vova, can you provide your example please? Because, I still cannot make it work. The `car` object still has correct fileds which have` String`, `Long`, `Integer` types, but `private User user` still is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from example you have some class that you want to test, lets call it `Handler`. In this Handler you use `CarService` to "build and store" car object, and to "find" car object (with some `User` verify) in DB. In CarService you use `CarDao` to work with DB.
So first: if you test Handler class then you need to mock IT OWN dependencies, it means that you need to mock CarService, but not CarDao inside CarService (not the second level of nested dependencies). You need to mock CadDao whenever you test CarService, and it should be separated test from CarHandlerTest.

And second: I simulate your example and it works, see the code below.

```
public class User {} //simple user just to verify not null

public class Car {
    private Long id;
    private User user;
    //getters ans setters
}

public class CarDao { //with stub methods because we will mock it
    public void persist(Car car) {}
    public Car getById(Long id) {return new Car();}
}

public class CarHandler {
    private CarService carService; //with setter
    public void foo() { // we will test this method
        User user = new User(); //it's like your example but without additional fields (like color)
        Car car = carService.create(user); // here we build and store new car
        Car sameCar = carService.findById(car.getId());
        assert car == sameCar;
    }
}

public class CarService {
    private CarDao carDao; //with setter
    public Car create(User user) {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setUser(user);
        carDao.persist(car); //here car should get id
        return car;
    }

    public Car findById(Long id) {
        Car car = carDao.getById(id);
        User user = car.getUser(); //this user should be not null in test
        assert user != null; //this assert for verify user
        return car;
    }
}
```

And most interesting part - test.

```
public class CarHandlerTest {
    static long lastCarId = 5;
    private CarHandler carHandler = new CarHandler();
    private CarService carService = new CarService();
    private CarDao carDao;

    @Test
    public void testFoo() throws Exception {
        carDao = Mockito.mock(CarDao.class);
        carService.setCarDao(carDao);
        carHandler.setCarService(carService);

        Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() { //I copy it from your example
            @Override
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                lastCarId++;
                Car car = (Car) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
                // here car.getUser() returns correct user object
                car.setId(lastCarId);
                Mockito.when(carDao.getById(car.getId())).thenReturn(car);
                return null;
            }
        }).when(carDao).persist(Mockito.any());

        carHandler.foo();
    }
}
```

You also can return `Car` from `foo()` method and verify everything in test.